# Height de un div

Tags: html, css

Tengo dos `div`, con `background` de dos colores diferentes, que ocupan toda la pagina y quiero que lleguen hasta abajo del todo, osea el 100%, hasta ahí lo consigo. Pero cuando el contenido ocupa mas del 100% y hay scroll el `div` ya no ocupa toda la pantalla, solo coge el 100% inicial.

```
<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contenido">
  </div>
</body>


html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0; 
  height:100%;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}
#menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color:#0174DF; 
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
}
#contenido {
  background-color: #58ACFA;
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega `overflow: auto;` en tus `<div>`. Basicamente esta propiedad `css` te permite indicar que pasara con el contenido dentro de un `<div>` con dimensiones ya definidas. Tienes 4 distintos valores para este atributo.

- visible : Muestra el contenido aun cuando no quepa dentro de las dimensiones definidas.
- hidden : Muestra solo el contenido que cae en las dimensiones definidas, lo demas se pierde.
- scroll : Muestra `scroll` en las cajas independiente si el contenido queda dentro o sale.
- auto : Respeta las dimensiones ya definidas pero muestra el contenido agregando el `scroll` si es necesario.

Sin `overflow`

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0; 
  height:100%;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}
#menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color:#0174DF; 
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
}
#contenido {
  background-color: #58ACFA;
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

 <body>
  <div id="menu">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contenido">
    <p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p>
  </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```

Con `overflow`

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0; 
  height:100%;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}
#menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color:#0174DF; 
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#contenido {
  background-color: #58ACFA;
  width: 80%;
  float:left;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>

 <body>
  <div id="menu">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contenido">
    <p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p><p>asdsadsadsadsadsadsad</p>
  </div>
</body>
    
</html>
```